# How to remove a word with CSS

Tags: css

Wordpress/woocommerce

I am trying to remove the following words from before the price:

```
ex. 

inc.
```

from `span.ex-vat-price` & `span.inc-vat-price`

I was able to add the correct wording this way after the price.

```
.woocommerce-variation-price .ex-vat-price:after {
    content: " ex. VAT";
}

.woocommerce-variation-price .inc-vat-price:after {
    content: " inc. VAT";
}
```

I can't find a solution on how to do it. If someone could help me please!

This is the link: https://eclaptops.co.uk/product/clevo-n151cu-15-6-win10-home/

Comment: With css you can't (you can only hide using display none)

Comment: Do you want to remove them in general or on a condition?

Comment: Your circumstances are unclear. Why don't you delete those words in html if you don't need them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. The words are hard coded on my theme. I am using wordpress/woocommerce. I just want to remove the words inc and & ex which are before the price.